# Failure to get the stage of a dialog

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/ shows how to get the stage of a JavaFX-8 dialog:

```
// Get the Stage.
Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
```

Alas, this does not work for me: the dialog pane (although displayed) gives `null` on `.getScene()`.

Is there any other easy way to get the stage or at least the scene of an open dialog window?

The background of the question is that, under certain circumstances, need to display an `Alert` to the user while keeping the underlying dialog window open. Currently, that does not work due to an invalid combination of `Modality` values, but that's a different topic.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: To just change the modality of a javafx.scene.control.Dialog (see background of this question) there is also this method: 

"javafx.scene.control.Dialog<R> public final void initModality(javafx.stage.Modality modality)
Specifies the modality for this dialog. This must be done prior to making the dialog visible."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say for sure if you post no context code but I think the problem is the timing. You need to get the stage before you showAndWait (or at least before the dialog is closed). Try this:

```
public static boolean showConfirmationDialog(String contentText, String headerText) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, contentText, ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
    alert.setTitle("Test");
    alert.setHeaderText(headerText);

    Window alertWindow = alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    System.out.println("alertWindow.getOpacity(): " + alertWindow.getOpacity());

    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

    //This would cause a NullPointerException at this point:
    //alertWindow = alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    //System.out.println("alertWindow.getOpacity(): " + alertWindow.getOpacity());

    return (result.get() == ButtonType.YES);
}
```

Comment: The problem was indeed the timing. The test happened in a change listener of the result property, and only fired after the dialog closed. Thank you for your help!